# Adjusting Views according to Admob banner size -ios

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, admob

Do i need to adjust the position of components in views in order to avoid  hiding them from Admob banner. Or is there any easy way to auto rearrange views when a add receive.

Answer (score 0):

The general recommendation is to just leave space for the banner at the bottom of the app, so you don't have to shift the rest of the elements in `adViewDidReceiveAd`.  If you are keen on making use of this space in the case that no ad return, you might find the new iOS 6 Auto Layout API helpful.

Comment: how about Admob smart banner? and iOS below iOS 6?

Comment: The recommendation still holds for smart banner and iOS 5 and below. Depending on your app, another option is to leave the space available for an ad, so that when it comes in, it just fills that space.